# String function pad or subsritng a staring in java

Tags: java, string

Currently I'm looking at a function where if a string is less than a certain length then add empty characters until the length is met.
Also if the text is longer than the specified length then remove the trailing characters from that string.

there are functions like `StringUtils.rightPad` and `subString` , but I'm looking for a function which does both of the tasks at once.

Comment: Can you show us some input output example, beside you can create your own function which can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can chain these calls to get the desired result:

```
public static String fitToLength(String s, int len) {
    return StringUtils.rightPad(s, len).substring(0, len);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function with this

String.format(String.format("%%%ds",n),x).substring(0,n);

public class Main {

```
public static String fixLen(String x,int n) {
    return String.format(String.format("%%%ds",n),x).substring(0,n);
}


public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    String x="test";
    String y=fixLen(x, 8);
    System.out.println("y="+y+"\tlen="+y.length());
    x="test1234567";
    String z=fixLen(x, 8);
    System.out.println("z="+z+"\tlen="+z.length());

}
```

}